# Add new row on last page using jquery

Tags: jquery, datatable

Hello,

I used data table plugin for my app. I must add new row, after that it need to redirect user to last page of pagination.
My problem is  when I create a new tag it is not saved on the last one.

```
   $('.btn-save').on('click', function () {
        validateField();
        let name = $('#name').val();
        let result = $('#checkbox-feed').is(":checked");
        let result2 = $('#checkbox-favorites').is(":checked");
        let selectedval = $('#select-tag :selected').text();
        var id =  $('#table_id tr').last()

        console.log(id)
        $('#table_id tr:last').after(`<tr class="content"><td></td><td class="tag-name" ><a href="#">${name}</a></td><td>${selectedval}</td><td class='${result ? "feed" : "no-feed"}'></td><td class='${result2 ? "favorite" : ""}'></td><td class="option-box"><button class="edit-btn"></button> <button class="delete-btn"></button></td></tr>`)
        var oTable = $('#table_id').dataTable();
        oTable.fnPageChange( 'last' );
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

$('#table_id > tbody').append(`<tr class="content"><td></td><td class="tag-name" ><a href="#">${name}</a></td><td>${selectedval}</td><td class='${result ? "feed" : "no-feed"}'></td><td class='${result2 ? "favorite" : ""}'></td><td class="option-box"><button class="edit-btn"></button> <button class="delete-btn"></button></td></tr>`)